# When we Get true while we use IsFixedSize Method in hashtable in C#?

Tags: c#, hashtable

so, I tried one program in C# of hashtable whenever I give a fixed size to the hashtable and then try out a method IsFixedSize it gives False. Then what is the reason behind it? (if size is fixed then also give false). Give an example which showcases true if we fetch the fixed-sized method.

```
using System;
  using System.Collections;
     class Program 
      {
           static void main()
            { 
                 Hashtable fixedSizeHashtable = new Hashtable(3)
                 {
                   { 1, "One" },
                   { 2, "Two" },
                   { 3, "Three" }
                 };
                 Console.WriteLine(fixedSizeHashtable.IsFixedSize); 
             }
        }
```

Comment: You [never will](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/hashtable.cs,809). You should probably also heed the recommendation in the documentation and stop working with the non-generic collections, outside of specialized applications.

Comment: It's for derived classes or wrappers to implement a fixed size hashtable

Comment: If you need collection that will have fixed size after initialization - take a look at new [FrozenSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.frozen.frozenset-1) added in net8

Comment: ^^ @JL0PD valid suggestion, but that's assuming OP is on .Net 8 (which is the newest available version at the time of writing).

Answer (score 4):

The capacity value that you pass to the `Hashtable` constructor has nothing to do with the `IsFixedSize` property. In other words, **the capacity value does not put an upper limit or does not fix the item size** of a `Hashtable`. When you add items, the capacity value is *automatically increased* as required based on the load factor. (Other collections may double the item count on each resize). For example you *can still add the fourth item* to your `Hashtable` when your initial capacity is three:

```
fixedSizeHashtable.Add(4, "Four");
```

The main concern of using the initial capacity in the constructor is to *eliminate* the need to perform redundant resizing operations *when you know* the approximate item count initially.

Look at the [Hashtable constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-collections-hashtable-ctor(system-int32)) for details.

Comment: Maybe it's also worthwhile to add this citation from the remarks-section: _"Specifying the initial capacity eliminates the need to perform a number of resizing operations while adding elements to the Hashtable object. **Capacity is automatically increased as required based on the load factor.**"_ (emphasis by me)

Comment: @Fildor: Actually these are the points that came to my mind after posting :) Edited accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [`IsFixedSize` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.isfixedsize?view=net-8.0) on the `Hashtable` class is a requirement from the [`IDictionary.IsFixedSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.idictionary.isfixedsize?view=net-8.0#system-collections-idictionary-isfixedsize) property from the [`IDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.idictionary?view=net-8.0) interface this `Hashtable` class is implementing. The `Hashtable` class allows dynamically adding and removing entries, which means the size cannot be fixed, therefore this property returns `false`. But since the class is not `sealed`, there can be other classes deriving from `Hashtable` which could have a fixed size.